# Exporting powershell script output to local SQLtable

Tags: sql-server, csv, powershell

I am trying to export the output of the below script to a local sql table directly instead of using CSV as a mediator. Is there a way to export the output of the below script directly to the local sql table.

```
Get-Content "C:\test\computers.txt" | Where-Object { $_.Trim() -ne "" } |
    ForEach-Object {
        Invoke-Command -Computer $_ -ScriptBlock {

            Param($computer)

            $Database = "secaudit"
            $AttachmentPath = "C:\test\SQLData.csv"
            $SqlQuery = "xp_fixeddrives"

            $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
            $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$computer;Initial Catalog=$Database;Integrated Security = True"

            $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
            $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
            $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

            $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
            $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd

            $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
            $nRecs = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

            $nRecs | Out-Null
            $objTable = $DataSet.Tables[0]
            $DataSet.Tables[0]
        } -ArgumentList $_ -Credential $cred

    } | Select-Object PSComputerName, Drive, "MB Free" |
        Export-Csv -Path "C:\test\output_space.csv" -NoTypeInformation

$query = @"
BULK INSERT [Test1].[dbo].[table_1] FROM "C:\test\output_space.csv" WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ",", ROWTERMINATOR = "\n")
"@

sqlcmd -S "CSCINDAE680687" -E -Q $query
```

Comment: Just a hint : paste all code, then select all of it and hit Ctrl+K to format : )

Comment: Consider using the SqlBulkCopy class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

Comment: @DanGuzman Do you happen to have any reference code for doing that? This is something I'm trying to put together myself, but if you've got code I'm happy to re-purpose somebody else's work ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example function that takes a connection string, target table name, and a data table of the rows to be loaded.  By default, columns are mapped by ordinal but you can use [SQlBulkCopyColumnMappings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.columnmappings.aspx) to specify different mappings, if needed.

```
Function Insert-TargetTable
{

    param(
          [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
            [string]$TargetDatabaseConnectionString
        , [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
            [string]$TargetTableName
        , [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
            [System.Data.DataTable]$DataTable
    ) 

    $bcp = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($TargetDatabaseConnectionString);
    $bcp.DestinationTableName = $TargetTableName;
    $bcp.WriteToServer($DataTable);
    $bcp.Close();

}
```